# Python to read txt files and delete lines that contains same part

Tags: python, text

I have a tons (1000+) of txt files that looks like this

```
TextTextText('aaa/bbb`ccc' , "ddd.eee");
TextTextText('yyy/iii`ooo' , "rrr.ttt");
TextTextText('aaa/fff`ggg' , "hhh.jjj");
```

What I want to achieve is to delete all lines that contains same "aaa" part, and leave only one line with it (remove all duplicates).

my code so far:

```
import os
from collections import Counter

sourcepath = os.listdir('Process_Directory3/')
for file in sourcepath:
    inputfile = 'Process_Directory3/' + file
    outputfile = "Output_Directory/" + file
    lines_seen = set()
    outfile = open(outputfile, "w")
    for line in open(inputfile, "r"):
        print(line)
        cut_line = line.split("'")
        new_line = cut_line[1]
        cut_line1 = new_line.split("/")
        new_line1 = cut_line1[0]
        if new_line1 not in lines_seen:
            outfile.write(new_line1)
            lines_seen.add(new_line1)
outfile.close()
```

My code is not working at all, I dont get any results
Console Report:

```
Line13 in <module>
    new_line = cut_line[1]
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

Sorry for my bad writing, it's my first post so far :D 
Best Regards

Update:

I added

```
startPattern = "TextTextText"
if(startPattern in line):
```

to make sure i target only lines that begins with "TextTextText", but for some reason I am getting .txt in destination folder that contains only 1 line of content "aaa".

In the end of the day, here is a fully working code:

```
import os
sourcepath = os.listdir('Process_Directory3/')
for file in sourcepath:
inputfile = 'Process_Directory3/' + file
outputfile = "Output_Directory/" + file
lines_seen = set()
outfile = open(outputfile, "w")

for line in open(inputfile, "r"):
        if line.startswith("TextTextText"):
            try:
                cut_line = line.split("'")
                new_line = cut_line[1]
                cut_line1 = new_line.split("/")
                new_line1 = cut_line1[0]
                if new_line1 not in lines_seen:
                    outfile.write(line)
                    lines_seen.add(new_line1)
            except:
                pass
        else:
            outfile.write(line)
outfile.close()
```

Thanks for a great help guys!

Comment: It seems to be in the right direction. What are your results? What is the problem?

Comment: may be empty line in your input file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `try-except` block in inner `for` loop. This will prevent your program from being interrupted if any error is encountered due to any line which doesn't contain `'` or `/`.

**Update:**

I've tried the code given below and it worked fine for me.

```
sourcepath = os.listdir('Process_Directory3/')
for file in sourcepath:
    inputfile = 'Process_Directory3/' + file
    outputfile = "Output_Directory/" + file
    lines_seen = set()
    outfile = open(outputfile, "w")

    for line in open(inputfile, "r"):
        try:
            cut_line = line.split("'")
            new_line = cut_line[1]
            cut_line1 = new_line.split("/")
            new_line1 = cut_line1[0]
            if new_line1 not in lines_seen:
                outfile.write(line) # Replaced new_line1 with line 
                lines_seen.add(new_line1)
        except:
            pass

    outfile.close() # This line was having bad indentation
```

**Input file:**

```
TextTextText('aaa/bbb`ccc' , "ddd.eee");
TextTextText('yyy/iii`ooo' , "rrr.ttt");
TextTextText('aaa/fff`ggg' , "hhh.jjj");
TextTextText('WWW/fff`ggg' , "hhh.jjj");
TextTextText('yyy/iii`ooo' , "rrr.ttt");
```

**Output File:**

```
TextTextText('aaa/bbb`ccc' , "ddd.eee");
TextTextText('yyy/iii`ooo' , "rrr.ttt");
TextTextText('WWW/fff`ggg' , "hhh.jjj");
```

Comment: When I try with this code I don't have any errors, just a blank .txt in destination folder.

Comment: @Directx995 I've updated my answer. `outfile.close()` was having wrong Indentation.

Comment: That works quite good, just need to figure out a way how to define to check only lines that begins with `"TextTextText"`, and copy all other lines regardless of content. when i try with `definePattern = "textexttext"` and use `if(definePattern in line)` then it wont copy the rest of files

Comment: The rest of content, not files*

Comment: @Directx995 To do so, add conditional statement `if line.startswith("TextTextText"):`  above `try-except` block. This will be `True` only for the lines which begin with `TextTextText`

Comment: Maybe it's something very very simple but I don't get it, when I add `if line` above `try-except` I am still getting only lines that begins with `TextTextText`...

Comment: Sorry. I didn't get your question. Can you please explain it again?

Comment: it was my mistake, I didn't add `outfile.write(line)` after else, so there was nothing to be written after `else`. Thanks one more time!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you encountered line inside your file which has not `'`, in this case `line.split("'")` produce `list` with single element, for example

```
line = "blah blah blah"
cut_line = line.split("'")
print(cut_line)  # ['blah blah blah']
```

so trying to get `cut_line[1]` result in error as there is only `cut_line[0]`. As this piece of your code is inside loop you might avoid that by skipping to next iteration using `continue` word, if cut_line has not enough elements, just replace:

```
cut_line = line.split("'")
new_line = cut_line[1]
```

by:

```
cut_line = line.split("'")
if len(cut_line) < 2:
    continue
new_line = cut_line[1]
```

This will result in ignoring all lines without `'`.

Comment: Thats true, I have blank lines, lines that start with /, etc. maybe it would be a nice solution if I can somehow add a command to look only for lines that starts with this "texttexttext"

Comment: @Directx995: remember about case-sensitivity that is `"TextTextText"` is different from `"texttexttext"`. To get only lines with given prefix, check out `str` method `startswith`, which returns `True` if `str` have given prefix and `False` otherwise. As you want to skip lines which do not have such prefi you need to use negation that is put `continue` in following if-block: `if not line.startswith("TextTextText")`

Comment: yeah sure that was a bit rushed answer :D if i understood you right it would be something like this:
`if line.startswith("TextTextText")`
`.........`
`outfile.write(line)`
and for the ones that doesnt i should use another 
`for rest_lines in open(inputfile, "r")`
use this to write the rest of the file?
Sorry again, I am absolute newbie in this all Python thing.

Comment: @Directx995: if you wish to have two output files, with second holding rest you need to use `else` for that `if`, i.e. something like `if line.startswith("TextTextText"):` *actions related to TextTextText lines including writing to output file* `else:` *actions related to rest of lines including writing to other output file*

Answer (score 0):

I think using a regular expression would make it easier. I have made a simplified working code using re.

```
import re

lines = [
        "",
        "dfdsa sadfsadf sa",
        "TextTextText('aaa/bbb`ccc' ,dsafdsafsA ",
        "TextTextText('yyy/iii`ooo' ,SDFSDFSDFSA ",
        "TextTextText('aaa/fff`ggg' ,SDFSADFSDF ",
    ]



lines_seen = set()
out_lines = []

for line in lines:

    # SEARCH FOR 'xxx/ TEXT in the line -----------------------------------
    re_result = re.findall(r"'[a-z]+\/", line)

    if re_result:
        print(f're_result {re_result[0]}')
        if re_result[0] not in lines_seen:
            print(f'>>> newly found {re_result[0]}')
            lines_seen.add(re_result[0])
            out_lines.append(line)

print('------------')
for line in out_lines:
    print(line)
```

Result

```
re_result 'aaa/
>>> newly found 'aaa/
re_result 'yyy/
>>> newly found 'yyy/
re_result 'aaa/
------------
TextTextText('aaa/bbb`ccc' ,dsafdsafsA 
TextTextText('yyy/iii`ooo' ,SDFSDFSDFSA
```

You can experiment with regular expressions here [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/).
Try **r"'.+/"** any character between ' and /, or **r"'[a-zA-Z]+/"** lower and uppercase letters between ' and /.